# SQL zero division

Tags: sql

How can I rewrite this SQL query to avoid division by zero errors in the ORDER BY?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE age>'30' ORDER BY (a/b) DESC
```

Comment: Ensure that `b` is never zero?  More seriously, what would you want the ordering to to when `b` *is* zero?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I want the value to be zero if b=0, not a specific value..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN b != 0 THEN a / b ELSE 0 END DESC
```

Comment: perhaps `b <> 0`, in case b is a signed value.

Comment: OP should be aware this will be all the rows with `B=0` at the bottom of the list.

Comment: That's what he wants, per his comment.